# можно ли вызвать команду при клике на "<- возврат" к предыдущей странице?

Tags: java, android

Android. Java. Надо, чтобы входе в активность А2  ВСЕГДА проверялось - получает ли приложение данные из Firebase (и если нет, то скрыть в этой активности Checkbox.)
Проверка нужна даже когда пользователь "возвращается на предыдущую активность А1" и снова переходит в А2.

**
(под словом "возвращается" имею ввиду не переход, а возврат, который происходит при клике не кнопке телефона "<-")

---

Проблема вот в чём:
Сейчас, когда возвращаюсь в А1 и отключаю интернрет (связь с Firebase должна теряться) и снова перехожу в А2      checkbox виден, а хочу чтобы стал невидимым (ведь связи нет)

Comment: Проверяйте коннект при старте А2 и выставляйте видимость - в чём проблема не понятно. А вообще коннект - штука не предсказуемая, он может пропасть как раз во время проверки и тут же вернуться, и во время работы А2 может пропадать, быть выключен и т.д.. Лучше ориентироваться на успешность запроса.

Comment: ... что имеете ввиду под "проверяйте при СТАРТЕ А2 "? прописать ещё одну проверку в onStart ?       (Сама проверка прописана в onCreate и по идее он должен выполняться в любом случае (хоть при перевороте, хоть при возврате на А2, ... но почему-то checkbox всё-равно виден, если до этого я заходил на эту активность с включенным интернетом. ..... ))

Answer (score 2):

Вы бы могли попробовать перезаписать метод `onBackPressed` и в нём написать ваши переменные которые нужно сбросить и присвоить им значение `null`. Пример:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    myVariable1 = null;
    myVariable2 = null;
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#onBackPressed())